grid tied inverter with PR controller giving unstable response
I am using MATLAB for the simulation of the solar grid-tied inverter. I have used designed the PR controller as shown in the paper. As far as I understood the PR controller is trying to remove any phase difference between the current and the grid voltage and grid current so that we get all the power as active. Some of the part of the circuits and results are shown below.

But upon seeing I figured out that I am not basically calculating the grid current and I therefore need to place the current sensor on the grid side not the inverter side. But upon simulating I found that the results were unstable and I couldnt get a propper response.
When I placed the current sensor to the left as shown in the paper it gave propper results.
I am confused why am I getting false results where is shouldnt be becasue I need to get the grid voltage and grid current injected in phase and for that I have to set a grid current reference not the inverter side current.
Kindly help solve this issue.
The image below is for shows the circuit and the results for the current sensor on the inverter side:


this is the real power transfered to the grid in blue:

But when using the current sensor on grid side by name of Iinv2 I get unstable result:


This is the response I am getting in blue for the real power when the sensor is on the right.

Even upon changing the values of the Kp and Kr I was getting the same result.
